# How to let webkit know the path of the libflashplayer.so and then use it?

Tags: linux, flash, ubuntu, webkit, gtk

I want to open a HTML file to play flash files, but Webkit doesn't have libflashplayer.so and I want to know how to let Webkit know the path of the libflashplayer.so and then use it to play flash files?

Comment: What about the executable `flashplayer`? You can get it from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html by selecting "Linux Flash Player 11.2 Projector" and placing the binary at `/user/bin/flashplayer`

Comment: Yes ,I foundd it in the path:/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/             but webkitgtk  still say "Missing Plugin".Is webkit really know the path of the libflashplayer.so?

Answer (score 2):

The following directories are where WebKit for QT searches for browser plugins. Have you tried these locations?

> ```
> .mozilla/plugins in the user's home directory
> .netscape/plugins in the user's home directory
> System locations, such as
>     /usr/lib/browser/plugins
>     /usr/local/lib/mozilla/plugins
>     /usr/lib/firefox/plugins
>     /usr/lib64/browser-plugins
>     /usr/lib/browser-plugins
>     /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
>     /usr/local/netscape/plugins
>     /opt/mozilla/plugins
>     /opt/mozilla/lib/plugins
>     /opt/netscape/plugins
>     /opt/netscape/communicator/plugins
>     /usr/lib/netscape/plugins
>     /usr/lib/netscape/plugins-libc5
>     /usr/lib/netscape/plugins-libc6
>     /usr/lib64/netscape/plugins
>     /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins
> ```

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtwebkit.html#netscape-plugin-support

Answer (score 0):

For firefox '**libflashplayer.so**' is placed in the '**/usr/lib/firefox-*/plugins**' directory and similarly there can be a directory for **webkit** in '**/usr/lib**'

(I am not sure about it, it's just a suggestion)

Comment: Yes ,I foundd it in the path:/usr/lib/webkitgtk-3.0-0/plugins            But webkitgtk still say "Missing Plugin".what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your question is very hard to answer. Because I do not think to know the path of plugin path will resolve this problem.

Anyway, I am sure you can use this function to know the path of webket plugin.

qgetenv("QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH");